# Why autoanalyze not ran when autovacuum performed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Team,
Recently identified one of the table autovacuum was in up to date but autoanalyze is not up to date. Parameters are configured default.
How this will happen? If autovacuum parameters satisfied the conditions then it should have performed autoanalyze as well .

Please share some insights on this.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Autovacuum and autoanalyze are triggered by different conditions and use different statistics counters:

- autovacuum starts running if the number of dead tuples (`n_dead_tup` in `pg_stat_all_tables`) exceeds a threshold (by default, about 20% of `reltuples` from `pg_class`).  From v13 on, there is a similar condition with `n_ins_since_vacuum`, the number of tuples inserted since the last `VACUUM`.
- autoanalyze starts running if the number of changed tuples (`n_mod_since_analyze` in `pg_stat_all_tables`) exceeds a threshold (by default, about 10% of `reltuples` from `pg_class`).

Whenever autovacuum or autoanalyze have completed, the respective statistics counter is reset to 0.

So there is no direct connection between autovacuum and autoanalyze runs (except that both are connected to table modifications, unless it is an anti-wraparound vacuum run).